# Как изменить default company domain in android studio?

Tags: android-studio

в сети полно гайдов как изменить Package name у уже существующего проекта.
Но нет ни одного про изменение стандартного имени которое генерируется для новых проектов.
Т.е. подскажите что сдеделать чтобы в мастере создания нового проекта строка "Package name" генерировалась не с текущим company domain

**com.example**.myapplication

а с новым
**ru.vasya**.myapplication

Comment: В настройках вообще не нашёл упоминания com.example, company domain, dafault package name или чегото подобного. Если создаю проект с новым доменом, следующему проекту всёравно генерируется старый.

Comment: мне что-то подсказывает что установить свое по-умолчанию нельзя, только в процессе создания можно установить новое имя либо после создания поменять название пакета

Comment: @Andrew , ан нет. у меня там стоит то, что я написал для первого проекта после установки студии: мой ник и название курса который читал. Мне что-то подсказывает что переустановка студии, это не лучшее решение :)